# How to use mixpanel with twitter bootstrap dropdown menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, mixpanel

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li class="dropdown" id="menu7">
           <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="username" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
             <%= current_user.full_name %>
             <b class="caret"></b>
           </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to('Edit my account', edit_user_registration_path, 
                  :id => 'edit_account') %></li>
            <li><%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => 'delete',
                  :id => 'logout_link') %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path, :id => 'login_link') %></li>
          <li><%= link_to('Sign up', new_user_registration_path, :id => 'signup_link') %></li>
        <% end %>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my javascript events are these:

```
  mixpanel.track_links('#username', 'Username clicked')
  mixpanel.track_links('#edit_account', 'Edit account link clicked')
  mixpanel.track_links('#logout_link', 'Logout link clicked')
```

I don't know why (i really looks bizarre!) only the event 'Username clicked' is working. Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Where you able to figure this out?

Comment: Is this related to your issue and solution?

[Tracking Links - emulating POST in rails](http://balazs.kutilovi.cz/2013/05/07/tracking-links-emulating-post-in-rails-with-mixpanel/)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you need to include the link tag in your selector:

```
  mixpanel.track_links('#username a', 'Username clicked')
  mixpanel.track_links('#edit_account a', 'Edit account link clicked')
  mixpanel.track_links('#logout_link a', 'Logout link clicked')
```

That's how it's done in the [Mixpanel doc](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript).

Another option is you may be going about this the wrong way. Instead of tracking clicks on links, maybe you want to use the ruby API and put your trackers in the controller, as shown in [this part of the doc](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ruby).

Thus, you would do something like this in your Users controller:

```
def edit
  track_event "edits account"
end
```

And in sessions conroller:

```
def destroy
  track event "logs out"
end
```